# Ionic start page image

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Good evening, if I can in some way to replace this picture in ionic start page ?

[[image: this image]]

Comment: in your config.xml change the value to none in the below line

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splash screen image can be modified by adding  a `splash.png, splash.psd or splash.ai` file within the resources directory at the root of the project[The source image's minimum dimensions should be 2208x2208 px].So there is **no need of adding different images for different screen size's**.

Then use below command from terminal,

```
$ ionic resources --splash
```

[**Refer**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)

**[Automating-icons-and-splash-screens](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/)**

Answer (score 1):

That's the splash screen.
When you add a platform through Ionic CLI using the command

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform add android
```

Ionic will add a folder called resources in the root of your project

Inside this folder you'll have all the images for the splash screen in many screen resolution and also the icon images. You'll have to replace them